# Two cards are drawn one after

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn one after another (without replacement) from a well shuffled pack of $52$ playing cards. Show the probability of getting or not getting a face card by drawing a tree diagram.

My attempt 
[image]

Is this the complete solution or something is missing?

Comment: Apart from your notation being rather akward., I would assume that the question is asking for the probability that *at least one of the two cards drawn* is a face card., so there is still one more step left to complete as this would correspond to $P(\{F\overline{F}\}\cup\{\overline{F}F\}\cup\{FF\})$.  You are also missing the calculations of the final results of the probabilities of each event.

Comment: I think question is not excluding the case with both face cards.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh what is the purpose of that comment?  Are you somehow implying that my comment is suggesting that...because it's not.

Comment: The confusion displayed by the previous comments shows you are not done. Clearly state the problem; then, in add'n to the diagram, bring together the relevant probabilities that add up to the answer.

Comment: @BruceET,  what are the relevant probabilities?  I am not being able to extract them.

Comment: @NeWtoN  $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B\mid A)$.  I.e. in your tree diagram, the probability of arriving at a specific *leaf* of the tree is the product of the probabilities to travel along each *branch* along the way.

Comment: Can't say which ones are relevant without knowing _exactly_ the question being asked: 'getting or not getting' seems to have been misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tree diagram looking correct. Once cross check your answer by solving question without tree diagram.

Output from tree diagram.

Case 1 -

Probability of getting at least one face card (including both are face cards) -

$\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{11}{51} + \frac{12}{52} \times \frac{40}{51} + \frac{40}{52} \times \frac{12}{51}$

Case 2 -

Probability of getting no face card -

$\frac{40}{52} \times \frac{39}{51}$

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Tried to sharpen English phrases a bit (before +1). Please re-edit if you think I changed your meaning.

Comment: @BruceET Its perfect now. Thank you.

Comment: @NeWtoN: First probability in your notation is $P(FF)+P(\bar F F)+P(F\bar F).$  Second is at bottom of your tree.